# Program installation recording for future manual installation

Tags: windows, installation

I routinely install the same software over and over on different computers. I would like to automate this process. Many times the software is very simple with the installer just adding a few entries into the registry and copying it's data to the installation folder.

I was thinking of using sandboxie to install all the apps to then load the hive and extract the registry data but I'm hoping there is already some software that will do what I'm asking for automatically?

The goal, if it is not clear, is simply to extract all the programs say from a zip, to the location I want to install them at(program files or whatever), modify the reg file to update the install locations(if I do not install to the default), then merge the reg file into the registry. (Since these programs are relatively simple there is no need to worry about any other issues)

Any utility's out there that can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/tracking-registry-and-files-changes-when-installing-software-in-windows/) for a list of several possibilities.

I used Thinstall (now called [ThinApp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ThinApp)) long ago, and it did the trick.

Comment: I don't app think Thin App will work. I don't want to create a portable app as these are actually plugin dll's(most of the time). Essentially(or effectively) I would like to create one big install for all my favorite apps and plugins that I can run once to install them. I don't like the compare before and after programs because they are slow. I'd prefer an app that monitors changes in real time.

Comment: Essentially I would like a mass installer type of app that lets me use it for my own apps. It monitors an install for reg and file changes then creates a simple install from those. It probably would be a simple program to write but I don't have time to do so.